# Managing DHTML templates in a web application project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, dhtml

I'm developing a fairly complex web application in Visual Studio.

This uses a lot of JavaScript-generated dynamic HTML. As a result, I find myself declaring a lot of string variables containing HTML templates. Some of these can be fairly complex, and it can get a bit messy.

In the past I wrote a tool that automatically compiled HTML files that had a particularly build type into a single JavaScript file. Along the lines of:

```
var res = {};
res.buttonTemplate = '<button>Text</button>";
```

This worked well, but I wonder how others approach this? Do you just tolerate (and minimise) the HTML strings, or do this differently?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a single HTML page with all the templates, and load that through jQuery, then reference templates within that..

```
<template class="button">
    <button>{0}</button>
</template>
```

...

```
<div id="templates"></div>
```

...

```
$("#templates").load("/templates.html");
```

...

```
var newElement = $($("#templates .button").html());
```

Comment: Thanks, you've made me aware of the template tag! It looks good, but I'd be concerned about ending up with a large HTML file due to a huge dump of templates being introduced.

Comment: Indeed, but you can always aggregate them together, or load several tags.